# Calling .destroy() by using a string

Tags: tkinter, destroy

I would like to kill the main tkinter window by passing a string, but the following code doesn't execute correctly:

```
from tkinter import *

btncmd = "win.destroy"

def killwin():
    eval(btncmd)
    
win=tk.Tk()

MyButton=ttk.Button(win, command=killwin)

win.mainloop()
```

The function killwin() is called but the main window isn't destroyed.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to define the button command as a string? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: Do you think that expression `win.destroy` will destroy `win`?

Comment: I would like to change button behaviour according to my main window‘s state. Button function is in a string array.

Comment: acw1668: Don‘t you think?

Comment: It should be `win.destroy()`.

Comment: Oh what a mistake......

Comment: It works, thank you!